# translate Gutenberg Custom blocks with WPML Translation management

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks, wpml

I have custom Gutenberg block. it works fine, now im trying to translate it with translation management. whatever I try to do it just not showing up in translation management.
what I want is to to have my custom block's field in translation management. please help me. ive been looking for the solution last 2 days.

ive trying to build custom blocks with plugin. nothing helps.

Comment: Did you use i18n strings for the fieldlabels? like `__('Label Name', 'theme-slug')`

Comment: Can you give a little more information about how your custom block is built? What kind of field(s) are in your custom block? If your custom block has fields that allow user input (e.g. a text field) then you need to tell WPML about it, which you can do using a language configuration file. The specifics about making custom blocks appear in the translation editor can be found on this [WPML docs page](https://wpml.org/documentation/support/language-configuration-files/#gutenberg-blocks).